# how to use external control attaching to a MFC program?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, mfc

I want to attach an external control in my MFC application so that i can use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Can you explain you specific problem, highlighting the programming question that you have. Your question as it stands is not in a form suitable for the site.

Comment: Now I've registered my control written by VC++6.0 and successfully added it to my C# program.But when i want to use it,the control's icon is gray and unable to use.I'm looking for the solution.